# Remove duplicates from list of DateTime objects only by Date component

Tags: scala, list, datetime, jodatime

What is preferred way to remove duplicates from list Joda DateTime objects but only by date component (no time component )

```
var dates = List[DateTime]()

dates = dates ::: List(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
dates = dates ::: List(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
dates = dates ::: List(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)) // different millisOfSecond

println(dates.distinct)
```

Results in

```
List(2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00,
     2011-01-01T00:00:00.001+01:00,
     2011-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a wrapper case class and override the equals method to do equality based on date component.

```
case class DateTimeWrapper(dt: DateTime) {
  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case x: DateTimeWrapper => x.dt.getDayOfMonth == this.dt.getDayOfMonth
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Here is the `distinct` method which uses `Set` to pick non duplicate elements

```
def distincts(list: List[DateTime]): List[DateTime] = {
  def helper(set: Set[DateTimeWrapper], list: List[DateTimeWrapper]) = list match {
    case Nil => set
    case x :: xs => if (set contains x) set else set + x
  }
  helper(Set.empty[DateTimeWrapper], list.map(DateTimeWrapper)).toList.map(_.dt)
}
```

Write an Implicit to make the API look better

```
implicit class ListUtils(list: List[DateTime]) {
  def distinctElems = distincts(list)
}
```

Usage:

```
val dates = List(
  new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)

println(dates.distinctElems.length)
```

Comment: The drawback is this will not account for time zone differences and thus might remove two dates which are actually different.

Comment: @ScottShipp ensure the dates are in same time zone before you call `distincts`

Answer (score 1):

Use the JodaTime DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance() method. This gives you a DateTimeComparator that compares only by date. See the API at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html

Comment: In case it is not clear since I was not explicit in my answer, you would use the comparator checking for 0 (equality between dates) and then use your favorite algorithm for removing duplicates. One approach might be to sort the list then iterate through it checking if the current item equals the previous one and if not, add it to a new list. The new list is the deduped list, once you have it return it.

Comment: I did something similar, but wondered what would be most idiomatic way to do it in Scala, i thought more elegant solution exists. I'm struggling with functional programming  so every time when i declare variable in this example var previous I think something better exists :)- some One liner

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
def orderAndDeleteDuplicatesList(unorderedList: List[DateTime]): List[DateTime] ={


if(unorderedList == Nil || unorderedList.isEmpty) return unorderedList


//order by millis
val sortedList : List[DateTime] =  unorderedList.sortBy(_.getMillis)
var previousElement :Option[DateTime] = None
var purgedAndSortedList = List[DateTime]() //return list
sortedList.foreach ( element  => {

  //Ako trenutni element nije jednak prethodnom ili je prethodni prazan dodaj ga na listu
  if(previousElement.isEmpty || dtc.compare(previousElement.get, element) != 0 ){
    purgedAndSortedList = purgedAndSortedList ::: List(element)
  }

  previousElement = Option(element)

})

purgedAndSortedList
}
```

DateComparator:

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeComparator}

private val dtc: DateTimeComparator = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance
```